# Background-image works fine on LocalServer but not displaying when accessed via Internet (DynDNS)

Tags: css, localhost, background-image, wampserver, dyndns

Have spent an hour trying to solve this - but to no avail.

I'm running WAMPserver on my main computer for development and am having no problem viewing my site from localhost. However, I've set up access to this local server over the Internet using DynDNS to show people what I'm working on. Works fine except that background-images don't show up when accessed this way. Everything else displays fine.

Am using relative paths for my background-image src (but have tried absolute paths - and the problem remains). And its not to do with my browser cache on my other computer (where I noticed this bug)(tried that).

Any ideas what might be happening?

Comment: which languages do you use to develop?

Comment: am primarily using html5/php/javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just upload image first and then give that path to image src.

 i.e `www.yoursitename.com/images/yourimage.jpg`